# Exported Blender UV Map is blurry

Tags: texturing, uv

I seem to have a problem that I cant find the solution for any where...

The problem I'm having is that when I export my UV Map and import into my editing program whether that be paint or paint.net I zoom in to the UV Island boundaries and I can see some blurriness and transparency; somewhat like it has some antialiasing. It would make my life easier if I could simply use the magic wand tool to select the right area for each face/island.

I've played with some of the settings in blenders UV tab in the UV editor and I cant seem to find anything that is fixing the problem with the exported texture. I apologize if I don't seem to make any sense, its hard to explain the problem im having and there are no solutions online from what I could find.

***Image of what it looks like in blender:***
[image: Image of what it looks like in blender]

***Image of what it looks like once exported into paint.net:***
[image: Image of what it looks like once exported into paint.net]

Thankyou in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the Blender Stack Exchange community, @RyanEarnshaw. It's standard procedure, here, to edit - cut -the images so that only the relevant parts appear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PNG will be anti-alliased.

Try to export your UV map as .SVG. It will be anti aliased too but you can change this. 
[image: export UV]

I'm using gimp (it's free). I don't know if you can do that in paint.net

Open your .SVG in gimp. Choose the size and check "Import Paths" and "merge imported Paths" (tried to translate).

[image: import svg in gimp]

in the "Paths" tab, click on "paint along path"

[image: paint path]

uncheck "antialiasing", choose your line width (color will be foreground color)

[image: parameters]

your lines will be exactly the color you want, nothing more, nothing less.

[image: final]

Comment: cheers man, this worked!

Comment: glad to help :)  be aware that diagonals won't be antialiased.

Answer (score 2):

That's caused to the low resolution of the image the UV map is mapped to; this resolution is the same that the file containing the UV layout will have when you export it.

To increase the resolution, press either the `New` or the `+` button, next to the name of the texture, depending on wether you already have another texture opened; then, a dialog box will appear, in which you can set the resolution of the texture slot - 1024 squared is the default, so use something like 4096 by 4096. You can change the `Generate Type` from *Blank* to *UV Grid*, and then press `Ok`.

[image]

Comment: followed your steps and it didnt fix my problem. I still get the blur around each island unfortunately.

Comment: @RyanEarnshaw That's basically inevitable; all you can do is make it higher resolution