# Exported UV map is blurry and doesn't line up with UV mapper(editor)

Tags: texturing

I'm just messing around with blender trying to learn how to use it. I'm on the texturing part of the model creation process, and I'm having issues I don't know how to deal with.

When I export the UV layout the lines are blurry. I assumed it was because of anti-aliasing.

[Blurry Lines http://www.chrispcr.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/blurry1.png](http://www.chrispcr.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/blurry1.png)

Googling the issue doesn't bring up much results. Maybe I'm wording it wrong?
I did find this:
[Exported Blender UV Map is blurry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24275/exported-blender-uv-map-is-blurry)

and:
http://dluat.com/exported-blender-uv-map-is-blurry/

It's the same question and answer.

Increasing the dimensions to 4096x4096 gave the same issue but its effect on the image was a lot smaller.

going the svg route gave roughly the same thing:

[svg blurry http://www.chrispcr.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/svg-blurry.png](http://www.chrispcr.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/svg-blurry.png)

That's fine, I just need to know what pixel the UV editor stops at, and keep that in mind while I paint.

I'll just throw in some markers to help:
[blender uv editor http://www.chrispcr.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/blender-UV-Editor.png](http://www.chrispcr.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/blender-UV-Editor.png)

Well, thats annoying, the editor doesn't even line up with image it created.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a work around that the pros use?

I'm assuming it has something to do with moving the vertices, in the UV editor, to have them line up with the image, but wouldn't that mess with the bump, displace, reflection, etc... maps? (I guess not if they're all lined up.)

Any help would be appreciated, and thanks in advanced.