# Cannot properly align textures

Tags: texturing

I'm making a cube. The half of the cube is green, the bottom is gray. It's supposed to be a precise split, but no matter what I do, it looks like this (image is of an edge of the cube):

[image: problem with textures]

One side is above the halfway point, the other side is below the halfway point. If I add a single pixel to the left side, it goes below the halfway point. Similarly, if I add a single pixel to the right side, it goes over the halfway point.

How do I precisely split the cube into green and brown, with the dividing line being exactly halfway between top and bottom?

This question is related: [Exported UV map is blurry and doesn't line up with UV mapper(editor)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28952/exported-uv-map-is-blurry-and-doesnt-line-up-with-uv-mappereditor) but it has no answers. I suspect I may have a similar problem, or at least I could fix my problem if I knew how to fix that other problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure that this isn't the simplest answer but you could split your cube in two pieces and make one piece green and the other brown. Than you could join (in the menu, object, join) the two pieces to one cube again.
(You can assign different colors to objects or to a part of an object in edit mode)

Comment: How do I get the two boxes to snap together?

[snap settings](http://i.imgur.com/GpRCx2A.png)

These are my snap settings, but the two boxes aren't snapping at all. Do I need to somehow tell Blender what object I want it to snap to?

Comment: After fiddling randomly for a bit, it snaps if I drag it well past the face (so I drag it into the other box, then it snaps back to where it should be). I'm going to just assume that's how it's supposed to work.